# How can my website delete another site's cookies?

Tags: http, cookies

I'd like to remove the cookies of another site from users on my site.  Is there any way to access the cookies from different domains.

Comment: Har Har Har.. Classic.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain why you want to do this there is another way to accomplish your end goal.

Comment: This shouldn't be voted down.. It's a perfectly valid question BTW.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids that. You can only view or set cookies that you set and that are valid for the current URL.

Answer (score 16):

No, of course not. That would be terrible. How would you like it if any site you went to could just read your stored password to any site you have saved?

Answer (score 7):

Try it and Google will block your site from Chrome and your whole site will end up being blacklisted as it appears to contain Malware! While it's not illegal, it's a kind of behaviour that makes you as popular on the Internet as the average spammer...

Furthermore, the storage of cookies depends on the browser that is used by the client. You don't have any control over that.

However, if the other site has an URL that will remove the cookie, you can inline that URL in an IFrame on your site so visitors of your site will call the cookie cleaner from the other site, thus clearing their cookie in a valid way. The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will apply in this case since it's the original site that clears it. But if the other site offers no such functionality then it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

The only place I can think that this you'd need this would be if you owned many domains, and you log in on one domain, you want to log off in another domain.

In php, the "setcookie" function has a way to specify a domain. You should put in the domain you wish for the cookies to be modified under. Then when you can erase/modify the cookies across all those domain.

Otherwise though, the answer is no, you cannot modify a cookie on another domain unless it gave you permission to modify such cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I certainly hope there's no way to do this! If there is a way, it's a bug in the browser security.

Obvious follow-up questions: Is there any way I can set something in a user's browser that will prevent him from accessing a competitor's site? Is there any way I can cause other people's web servers to explode and kill everyone in the building?