# Clear cookies from a website using php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to clear all the cookies of a particular website in the users browser when a person runs a php script in my website.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399901/how-can-my-website-delete-another-sites-cookies

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete all cookies of my website in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Go through all of your cookies and run this:

`setcookie("cookie_name", $site_name, time()-timeout);`

Comment: You can only modify the cookie visible from within your website, so if you're trying to delete another website's cookies you can't. Your question was a bit confusing, but I thought this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Can i delete all the cookies from that site without entering a particular cookie name?

Comment: You can't delete another site's cookies from your site. You can only delete your cookies.

Comment: I meant i know the cookie names from the site, but there are around 20 of them, so instead of writting 20 lines can i do it in a single line by just giving the site name?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question. It has a function for deleting all the cookies in your domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310558/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-my-website-in-php

Comment: @hablema - Try a `for` loop in this case to delete the 20 cookies for **YOUR** site. But why have so many cookies in the first place?

Comment: Yeah 20 cookies seems a little excessive.

Comment: @Recursed - too many cookies you get fat and then life gets difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as the browser maintains the cookies for that web site, not your web site. This would be a breach in the contract between the web server and the browser.

Also it is up to the browser to handle cookies in the way that it sees fit - after all a cookie is asking the browser to do the web server a favour by storing some info between web page visits from that server (domain).

But if the cookies are from your domain/server then you can ask the browser to either make them time out or give them an invalid value.