# Create a siplier way for user to delete his cookies?

Tags: cookies

Is it possible to provide a simplier way for my users to delete their cookies?
Most of our users dont even know where are the browser settings so we would like to provide a simple way for them to do it.

We cant expect from all of our members to know or be able by them self to clear specific cookie so we need to do it as mush as possible easier for them. If there is still need of any simple action to be done by the user in order to get it deleted then that doesnt bother me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my website delete another site's cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399901/how-can-my-website-delete-another-sites-cookies)

Comment: I think this is not possible. Your cookies are from your site, and you have no business deleting cookies from other sites. It is not like **you** own the browser of your user! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399901/how-can-my-website-delete-another-sites-cookies

Comment: Yes, I agree with all security rising issues. Thanks for the link.
Is it possible to create more simple way for our users to delete their cookies by them self?

Comment: That again is a super-broad question; and heavily depends on the type of browser, version, ...